# how to free unsubmitted iOS app name for App Store use

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I wanted to change the name of one of my apps that is already in App Store and I checked the app name availability by creating a new app in iTunesConnect.  Now I have a new iOS app project with the name I want my existing app to have and I want to delete that new app project from iTunesConnect and free the app name so I can use it.

I checked past posts on SO and it recommended deselecting all the regions in pricing and saving, but the newer version of iTunesConnect apparently won't let me save without specifying at least 1 region.

Does anyone know how to do that in the new iTunesConnect?

Thanks-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to change just app name then you can change it at update of the app when you update version for your app you can change name for app and your previous app name will be released automatically

Comment: That's so easy it's almost scary.